# How do I generate numbers according to zipf's law in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, math, zipf

For an array `arrayType arrayName[size] = . . .`, I want a function `arrayType sample() { . . . }` to return items from `arrayName` according to zipf's law (item in position n should have a frequency of m/n where m is the frequency of the first and most common item). I'm not even sure where to start, and I've found similar questions, but only with more specific cases.

I've tried simple searching, precision searching, forum trolling in various places, YouTube videos, and Quora but all to no avail, so I'm here. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Write a negative linear function, apply it to some value, then exponentiate it.

Comment: You can use `std::discrete_distribution` with weights 1, 1/2, 1/3, ..., 1/n.